# Why do obstructive lung diseases increase total lung capacity and residual volume?

Tags: lungs, respiratory-system, pulmonology

The explanation I can find is that they restrict exhalation due to constricted airways. However, consequentially inspiration should be restricted too, right?

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Questions here are required to show results of prior research. As described in the [help] and [this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/411/is-it-ok-to-ask-questions-that-dont-show-any-research), this demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and helps you get more specific and relevant answers. Please edit your question with links to or references to what you've found in your search. Otherwise your question may be closed.